# Peer not aunthenticated error

Tags: android

My build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        name "jcenter"
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
}
```

I am getting the error Peer not authenticated and i am unable to sync the gradle.
How to solve this issue?

Comment: you can write `google()` in repositories section directly without mentioning `url` and `name`.

Comment: It is not working